# CSS when resizing window

Tags: jquery, resize, location, reload, window-resize

I have this website: http://www.sfrpsicologia.com. When the green div is charged, this div has a different height and margin-top depending on the browser window. But, the problem is that when I resize the window, it doesn´t change this properties inmediately but only when I refresh the web (f5). How could I get that when I resize the window it takes inmediately those characteristics? I dont want to reload the page when resizing... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you have to encapsulate your "height/width"-calculating code into:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
      // your code here
});
```

since this will not be triggered on page load, you'll have to trigger it on the first time:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    // your code here
}).trigger('resize');
```

see [jQuery - resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it seems that still doesn't work: http://www.sfrpsicologia.com. You can see that if you open the website with a small window, the margin top of the green div wrapp is ok but when resizing the result is not good. It doesn´t do it. Only works when refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).bind("resize", function () {
    console.log('window resized. Recalculate your dimensions');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QtaZr/)